# getting an error "Http failure response for https://localhost:44328/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index: 0 Unknown Error"

Tags: angular, .net-core

I am very new to angular. I am making a small application that displays a list of projects that is coming from database on angular side. I am making a call from angular to .net core 2.2. The data comes from .net core side and I am trying to display that data on angular side,  but I keep getting below error:

[image]

My startup class in .net core look like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddDbContext<KPIContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                //app.UseHsts();
            }

           // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors(x=>x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

I tested my class in .net core side and I can see the data. My call to the .net core class from angular is below:

```
LoadProjectData() {
      this.dataservce.getProjectData().subscribe((tempdate) => {
      this.projectlist = tempdate;
      console.log(this.projectlist);
      if (this.projectlist.length > 0) {
        this.dataavailbale = true;
      }
      else {
        this.dataavailbale = false;
      }
     }), err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
  }
```

Below is my getProjectData()

```
  getProjectData() {
     return this.http.get<AllItProject[]>(ROOT_URL + '/Index');
  }
```

Root_URL is

```
export const ROOT_URL: string = 'https://localhost:44328/api/AllItProjectsLists';
```

I added this in my startup class:

```
app.UseCors(x=>x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

still, I keep getting the above error. My .net core 2.2 code is below:

```
namespace KPIWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AllItProjectsListsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly KPIContext _context;

        public AllItProjectsListsController(KPIContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/AllItProjectsLists/Index
        [HttpGet("Index")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AllItProjectsList>>> GetAllItProjectsList()
        {
            return await _context.AllItProjectsList.ToListAsync();
        }
```

when I run my controller code and type the below URL on the browser, I can see the data and thats what made me think that I don't have any error on my .net core code.

```
https://localhost:44328/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you see on the network tab?

Comment: can  you post the code from API method?

Comment: expand the first error array in log it will help to know error in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status 0 means that the server is not up in my case.